# Execute Query depending upon select query value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

How to achieve the following query -

```
SELECT 
   CASE 
      WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 
         -- UPDATE operation
      ELSE 
         -- INSERT operation
   END AS [RESULT] 
FROM 
   [TABLE_1] 
WHERE 
   [CONDITION]
```

I am using SQL Server 2000.
Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use EXISTS not COUNT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271455) as per my answer

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [TABLE_1])
    UPDATE [TABLE_1] SET X = Y WHERE [CONDITION]
ELSE 
    INSERT INTO [TABLE_1] (X) VALUES (Y)
```

If you expect a very high proportion of updates, then why touch the table twice?

```
UPDATE [TABLE_1] SET X = Y WHERE [CONDITION]
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 
    INSERT INTO [TABLE_1] (X) VALUES (Y)
```

You can't do the same for a very high proportion of INSERTs on SQL Server 2000: [you need TRY/CATCH to handle duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407857/3408196#3408196) as per my answer

Answer (score 1):

By far the easiest way to do this is to have two separate queries, something like:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [TABLE_1]) > 0
    UPDATE [TABLE_1] SET X = Y WHERE [CONDITION]
ELSE 
    INSERT INTO [TABLE_1] (X) VALUES (Y)
```

Comment: I'd actually uses EXISTS rather than count