# Efficient Linq Enumerable's 'Count() == 1' test

Tags: c#, linq

Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958492/sql-making-count-1-efficient) but rephrased for Linq:

You can use `Enumerable<T>.Any()` to test if the enumerable contains data.  But what's the efficient way to test if the enumerable contains a single value (i.e. `Enumerable<T>.Count() == 1`) or greater than a single value (i.e. `Enumerable<T>.Count() > 1`) without using an expensive count operation?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

```
int constrainedCount = yourSequence.Take(2).Count();

// if constrainedCount == 0 then the sequence is empty
// if constrainedCount == 1 then the sequence contains a single element
// if constrainedCount == 2 then the sequence has more than one element
```

Comment: make sure you don't work with the yourSequence data itself because skipping or taking might lose/comsume the data in some cases. it is ok if you are only concerned about the count.

Answer (score 17):

One way is to write a new extension method

```
public static bool IsSingle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable) {
  using (var enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator()) {
    if (!enumerator.MoveNext()) {
      return false;
    }
    return !enumerator.MoveNext();
  }
}
```

Comment: @CodeArtist One measurement is worthless. You need to calculate an average and standard deviation. On my machine the difference is meaningless.

Answer (score 11):

This code take's LukeH's excellent answer and wraps it up as an `IEnumerable` extension so that your code can deal in terms of `None`, `One` and `Many` rather than `0`, `1` and `2`.

```
public enum Multiplicity
{
    None,
    One,
    Many,
}
```

In a static class, e.g. `EnumerableExtensions`:

```
public static Multiplicity Multiplicity<TElement>(this IEnumerable<TElement> @this)
{
    switch (@this.Take(2).Count())
    {
        case 0: return General.Multiplicity.None;
        case 1: return General.Multiplicity.One;
        case 2: return General.Multiplicity.Many;
        default: throw new Exception("WTF‽");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Another way:

```
bool containsMoreThanOneElement = yourSequence.Skip(1).Any();
```

Or for exactly 1 element:

```
bool containsOneElement = yourSequence.Any() && !yourSequence.Skip(1).Any();
```

Comment: This is what I've tended to use but LukeH's constrained count is pretty nifty.

Comment: @Paul - Yeah, it wraps up the `seq.Any()` and `seq.Skip(1).Any()` into one nice statement.

Comment: You'll need to pair this up with something else to see if the count is 1. This covers the > 1 scenario, however.

Answer (score 4):

Efficient `Count() == n` test:

```
public static bool CountIsEqualTo<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, int c) 
{
    using (var enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator()) 
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < c ; i++)
            if (!enumerator.MoveNext()) 
                return false;
        
        return !enumerator.MoveNext();
    }
}
```

Edit, 11 years later:
Nowadays I'd probably write this as

```
public static bool CountIsEqualTo<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, int c) 
{
    return enumerable.Take(c + 1).Count() == c;
}
```

It's a generalized version of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

With linq to objects, SingleOrDefault throws if there is more than one element, so you're probably best off if you roll your own.

**EDIT**: Now I've seen LukeH's answer, and I have to say I prefer it. Wish I'd thought of it myself!

Comment: Single() throws - SingleOrDefault() will return the default value for the generic type (null for reference types).

Comment: @David: Nope, `SingleOrDefault` will throw if there is more than one element. It only returns `default(T)` if there are no elements.

Comment: @David, his comment about `SingleOrDefault` is true. The difference between `Single` and `SingleOrDefault` is not whether they throw, only when.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool hasTwo = yourSequence.ElementAtOrDefault(1) != default(T);
```

...in case of class where values can be null this could maybe we useful.