# How can I efficiently determine if an IEnumerable has more than one element?

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

Given an initialised `IEnumerable`:

```
IEnumerable<T> enumerable;
```

I would like to determine if it has more than one element. I think the most obvious way to do this is:

```
enumerable.Count() > 1
```

However, I believe `Count()` enumerates the *whole* collection, which is unnecessary for this use case. For example, if the collection contains a very large amount of elements or provided its data from an external source, this could be quite wasteful in terms of performance.

How can I do this without enumerating any more than 2 elements?

Comment: if you have to count on it, then do something, you'd be better off forcing it to evaluate into a list or other collection.

Comment: @devshorts, by *count on it*, do you mean *depend on it working* or *use the `Count()` method*?

Comment: I mean if you need to find how many elements are on it, then do something depending on that, you might as well evaluate it. `Count` will evaluate it once, and then if you iterate it again you have to evaluate everything again. Same with any other `IEnumerable` methods, like `Take`, or `Skip`.  It really depends what the data is.

Comment: @devshorts, thanks; I agree that it's important to not double-enumerate. However, keep in mind that there could also be cases where you only care about this single criterion and don't want to do any other work on the enumerable.

Comment: @devshorts, are you implying that `Take` and `Skip` enumerate the whole enumerable? I haven't looked at the implementation, but I don't think that would be the case since it's inefficient and not technically necessary.

Comment: You might want to consider sticking with `Count()` if the underlying `IEnumerable` is an `Array`, `ICollection` or `IQueryable` as `Count()` is optimized to detect those and use the Length/Count property as appropriate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Test if an IEnumberable<T> contains more than 1 element without Counting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447846/test-if-an-ienumberablet-contains-more-than-1-element-without-counting)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can test this in many ways by combining the extension methods in System.Linq... Two simple examples are below:

```
bool twoOrMore = enumerable.Skip(1).Any();
bool twoOrMoreOther = enumerable.Take(2).Count() == 2;
```

I prefer the first one since a common way to check whether `Count() >= 1` is with `Any()` and therefore I find it more readable.

Comment: This isn't always valid, if this is a stream of data you've lost the data you skipped and/or took.  Also if the data is changing each time you act on the enumerable, this means your evaluation of the data can be different after you've done this test.

Comment: @devshorts but he's only concerned about the count, not the actual data.

Comment: @devshorts True. Of course you could save the Take(2) result into a variable if necessary, but that wasn't a requirement in the question.

Comment: @DennisRongo, you're right, but he is also asking if the ienumerable is underlying a large data source or external stream, in which case doing a take/skip on it you've lost the data.  Now you need to create a new enumerable to prefix the data you took.  Possible, just ugly.

Comment: @devshorts, isn't it impossible to meet my criteria without losing the data (in your sense) by enumerating at least 2 elements?

Comment: @devshorts, the mention of use of an external data source was just to emphasise the importance of not enumerating more elements than necessary. For this question, I'm not concerned about these other concerns. I've slightly re-worded it to try to clarify this.

Comment: @devshorts, after seeing the other answer suggesting a prefetching `IEnumerable`, I can now see how this can be done without potential data loss/corruption.

Comment: @Sam that is what this does too. It just doesn't save the intermediate result, which could easily be saved (e.g. `Take(2).ToList()`).

Comment: @CameronS, the prefetching/caching `IEnumerable` solution should allow you to re-use the enumerable without starting a new enumeration, which I think would alleviate the problem of the data being different for each enumeration. I'm not saying there's a fault with your solution for my question; I'm just correcting an earlier comment I made in which I incorrectly thought it was impossible to do what @devshorts suggested.

Comment: What we don't know is the relative efficiency of Count() vs using both Any() and Take(1).Any(). It's easy to think of scenarios where either one is more efficient, depending on the time to get the first element vs the number of elements. However when you use Take(2).Count() == 1, it's a lot harder to think of cases where that is less efficient than Count().

Answer (score 5):

For the fun of it, call Next() twice, then get another IEnumerable.

Or, write a small wrapper class for this specific goal: `EnumerablePrefetcher : IEnumerable<T>` to try and fetch the specified amount of items upon initialization.

Its `IEnumerable<T> GetItems()` method should use yield return in this fashion

```
foreach (T item in prefetchedItems) // array of T, prefetched and decided if IEnumerable has at least n elements
{
  yield return item;
}
foreach (T item in otherItems) // IEnumerable<T>
{
  yield return item;
}
```

Comment: Thanks; I hadn't thought about making a prefetching or caching `IEnumerable`!

Comment: The code sample can be expressed as `return prefetchedItems.Concat(otherItems);` although the above is also solid.

Comment: @CameronS, I only just realised `Concat` existed; thanks! I'd thought such functionality was missing from the framework.

Answer (score 3):

@Cameron-S's solution is simpler but below is more efficient. I came up with this based on `Enumerable.Count()` method. `Skip()` will always iterate and not short-circuit to get `source`'s count for `ICollection` or `ICollection<T>` type.

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns true if source has at least <paramref name="count"/> elements efficiently.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>Based on int Enumerable.Count() method.</remarks>
public static bool HasCountOfAtLeast<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, int count)
{
    source.ThrowIfArgumentNull("source");
    var collection = source as ICollection<TSource>;
    if (collection != null)
    {
        return collection.Count >= count;
    }
    var collection2 = source as ICollection;
    if (collection2 != null)
    {
        return collection2.Count >= count;
    }
    int num = 0;
    checked
    {
        using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                num++;
                if (num >= count)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // returns true for source with 0 elements and count 0
    return num == count;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar need, but to get the single value from an IEnumerable if it only has a single value. I made an extension method for it:

```
public static S OneOnlyOrDefault<S>(this IEnumerable<S> items)
{
    var rtn = default(S);
    using (var en = items.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (en.MoveNext())
        {
            rtn = en.Current;
        }
        if (en.MoveNext())
        {
            rtn = default(S);
        }
    }
    return rtn;
}
```

To answer the question *does this collection contain only 1 item?* You could do (where the collection contains reference types in this case):

```
if (myList.OneOnlyOrDefault() == null)
{
    // list is either empty or contains more than one item
}
```