# MySQL 'if exists' error

Tags: mysql, exists

I got a error in my MySQL query:

```
if not exists(select * from tb_user where user_id=1) then
     select 'ok' as rul;
else
     select 'not' as rul;
end if;
```

Where's my problem?

Comment: You may also want to check on this [performance of count(*) vs exisits post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264658/is-exists-more-efficient-than-count0) to embark in the best solution for you. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another method: You may also use `case when`

```
Select case
when exists(select * from tb_user where user_id=1)
then 'Ok'
else 'Not'
end
;
```

### * [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c070b/1)

Sample table:

```
ID  NAME
1   john
2   tim
3   jack
4   rose
```

Query: renamed the columns as `Status`

```
Select case
when exists(select * from table1 where id=1)
then 'Ok'
else 'Not'
end as Status
;
```

Results:

```
STATUS
Ok
```

Answer (score 4):

The IF statement can only be used in stored functions. You can do what you want with the IF() function, as follows:

```
SELECT IF(EXISTS(select * from tb_user where user_id=1), 'ok', 'not') as rul;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT IF(COUNT(*) > 0, 'ok', 'not') rul FROM tb_user WHERE user_id = 1;
```