# get success/failure response from mysqli_query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm gathering info from a user and then adding them to a table.

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO jos_activeagents (RINGPHONE, AGENTUID, FNAME, LNAME) VALUES ('(618) 717-2054','".$result['AGTBRDIDMM']."','".$result['AGTFNAME']."','".$result['AGTLNAME']."')";

$set = mysqli_query($link,$insert);
```

`AGENTUID` is a unique key.  If a user tries to submit with a duplicate unique key, I get an error (of course).

Now, how would I go about knowing if and when an error occurred and then putting a response back to the page?  I know of `mysqli_get_warnings()`, but the PHP manual doesn't show any examples.

I have also tried looking for the `AGENTUID` in the table first:

```
$check = "SELECT * FROM jos_activeagents WHERE AGENTUID = '".$agt."'";

$runcheck = mysqli_query($link,$check);

$rescheck = mysqli_fetch_assoc($runcheck);

if($rescheck != null){

    echo 'This Agent ID is already enrolled.'

}
```

But this seems sloppy.  Is there a better way do this?

Comment: do not use mysql_* because... oh wait, someone that don't use mysql_*! congratulations! :D

Comment: While not using mysql_*, the data is being put directly inside of the query. If this isn't just an example, still possibly vulnerable to SQL injections!

Comment: @WouterH: Even with the use of mysqli_real_escape_string?  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: mysqli_query does **NOT** return null. either you get a statement handle, or a boolean false if there was a failure.

Comment: You shouldn't need to use the escaping functions directly if you're using [SQL placeholders](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and `bind_param`. Do not use string concatenation to compose queries. You will get yourself into trouble eventually.

Comment: @MarcB: ok, so proper syntax is `if($whatever != false)`?

Comment: `if (!$result) { die(mysqli_error());`. a select which returns no rows is **NOT** a failure. it's still a valid result set that happens to be an empty set. you need to explicitly check how many rows were (not?) retrieved, or try and fetch a row from the result set. fetching from an empty result set also returns false. never null.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`mysqli_error()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to see if an error occurred

```
if (mysqli_error($runcheck ))
{
   // an error eoccurred
}
```

In your particular example you're better of checking if the row exists *before* doing the insert. Your example is close but would better using [`mysqli_num_rows()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php):

```
$check = "SELECT * FROM jos_activeagents WHERE AGENTUID = '".$agt."'";
$runcheck = mysqli_query($link,$check);
if (mysqli_num_rows($runcheck) > 0)
{
    // username in use
}
```

Comment: This approach uses a single query and returns a string indicating the status of the insert: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13985950/mysql-if-exists-error

Comment: don't know why you hadn't got an up vote for a right answer. +1 my fellow chum