# What is faster - `findOneBy()` or `countBy()`? [Sf6, Doctrine]

Tags: php, performance, symfony, doctrine

I am using Symfony 6 and Doctrine and I want to check if a specific entry in my database exists.

**ExampleEntity**

- id
- field1
- field2

I want to check if an entity with `field2='test'` exists in the database.

What will be faster? And why?

```php
$value='test';

## countBy()
$count = $repository->countBy(['field2' => $value]);
if($count > 0) { return true;}

## findBy()
$entity = $repository->findOneBy(['field2' => $value]);
if($entity) { return true;}
```

Comment: Should be faster to use findOneBy since it would stop once one entity is found, counyBy will search your criteria for the entire base

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken countBy is not a method available in Symfony 6; although even if it was, I would presume that findOneBy would be faster.

Comment: As for all similar questions: there is some reasoning why `findOne` would be faster (as it should stop once an element is found) but without knowing the internals of either function, your environment and your data it's impossible to say one is significantly faster as the other one. You'll have to do a benchmark with *your data*  and *your environment*

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you have a small bug, you can not use this code:

```php
$count = $repository->countBy(['field2' => $value]);
```

It will throw an `InvalidMagicMethodCall` exception.

So, you should consider one of these options:

```php
$count = $repository->count(['field2' => $value]);
// or
$count = $repository->countByField2($value);
```

**Now, let's consider two working cases:**

```php
// first case
$count = $repository->count(['field2' => $value]);

// second case
$entity = $repository->findOneBy(['field2' => $value]);
```

In the first case, the ORM Doctrine will build an SQL query, something like:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM example t0 WHERE t0.field2 = 'test';
```

In the second case, Doctrine will build:

```sql
SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.field1 AS field1_2, t0.field2 AS field2_3 FROM example t0 WHERE t0.field2 = 'test' LIMIT 1;
```

**Query from second case (with `findOneBy`) would be faster**, you can find more details here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19998743/7687226

However, if you have a secondary index for the `field2` column, then the **query from the first case (with `count`) would be faster due to the covering index situation.**

Answer (score 2):

Symfony 6.3 nor Doctrine have a `countBy` method. However, if instead we used count() -- which is what I presume you mean...

*When it comes to performance, there is no clear winner based on your hypothetical example.*

The **reason** is that fundamentally the two function differently. `FindByOne` will stop traveling as soon as it finds a match, whereas `Count` will travel the entire table. Now Count has some internal optimizations within SQL that makes it more performant than even FindByOne when the result (hit) is near the end of the table.

This carries over to real world tests -- when I take a database of 50,000 records, if the "hit" is near the front, then FindByOne finishes nearly 3x faster than Count, however when the "hit" is near the end, then FindByOne finishes 50% slower than Count. And if the "hit" was near the middle, then Count again wins by a margin. But all of this is still measured in the *single digit milliseconds (ms)*

Considering that in most cases you *probably will not know* where the match will be found, using `Count` will probably be faster more often than not if you're simply trying to confirm if an entry exists.

Comment: No, `count` would be slower in this situation. It can be faster only if a secondary index exists for the `field2` column.

Comment: ORM Doctrine allows you to call a method `countByField` via the magic method `__call`. But under the hood it is the same `count` method https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/2.16.x/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php#L279

Comment: @OlegDemkiv -- at first glance it might seem that it would be true -- because, after all, `count` would have to traverse over the entire table versus `findByOne` which can stop immediately after being found. But the *reality* is that there is some being the scenes optimizations (that is why `count(*)` doesn't run as poorly as you might think)... But beyond that, in real-world testing, against non-indexed columns, it is truly faster -- both within Symfony, but even as a raw SQL query (as you demonstrated below which comes from Symfony's profiler) MySQL Workbench and viewing the statistics.

Answer (score -1):

In Symfony 6 and Doctrine:

Use countBy() for a quick check if an entity exists based on specific criteria. It's efficient as it counts matching records directly without retrieving full entities.

Choose findOneBy() when you need to work with the entity's data after confirming its existence. It fetches the entire entity, allowing access to its properties. However, it's less efficient due to data retrieval.

For an authentic decision, consider your use case: simple existence check or data interaction. Prioritize performance by benchmarking both methods in your application.

Comment: countBy() is not implemented in Symfony.