# Self joining doesn't help here. What other approach can I use?

Tags: mysql

I am stuck with this problem. Consider the following table. I only know the value A(i.e. I can use something like `SELECT * from table WHERE user_one = A`). I tried doing a self join, but that didn't help.

**Given table**

```
+----------+-----------+---------+
| USER_ONE |  USER_TWO |  STATUS |
+----------+-----------+---------+
|          |           |         |
| A        | B         | 0       |
|          |           |         |
| B        | A         | 1       |
|          |           |         |
| A        | C         | 1       |
|          |           |         |
| C        | A         | 1       |
|          |           |         |
| D        | A         | 1       |
|          |           |         |
| A        | E         | 0       |
+----------+-----------+---------+
```

My desired result needs to be the following. Imagine `user_one` is following `user_two` if status is 1.Status 0 means, the `user_one` was previously following `user_two`, but now he unfollowed `user_two`. I need the users Who are following "A". Notice that I **don't want**, the rows where they are both following each other like `(A -> B)` and `(B -> A)` both has Status 1. So the question to the following response would be something like, "Find me people following A, but A is not following them", makes sense? A little help would be appreciated.

**Desired Rows**

```
+----------+-----------+---------+
| USER_ONE |  USER_TWO |  STATUS |
+----------+-----------+---------+
|          |           |         |
| B        | A         | 1       |
|          |           |         |
| D        | A         | 1       |
+----------+-----------+---------+
```

Comment: A hint: providing a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with sample datacan increase the possibilty of getting a (correct) answer.

Comment: @FirstOne, sure, give me few minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

**Using count(*)**

```
select
    t1.user_one,
    t1.user_two,
    t1.status
from
    table t1
where
    t1.status = 1 and
    -- t1.user_two = 'A' and -- If looking for people following user A in specific then uncomment this line
    (select count(t2.*)
     from table t2
     where t2.status = 1 and
           t2.user_two = t1.user_one and
           t2.user_one = t1.user_two) = 0
```

**Using not exists**

```
select
    t1.user_one,
    t1.user_two,
    t1.status
from
    table t1
where
    t1.status = 1 and
    -- t1.user_two = 'A' and -- If looking for people following user A in specific then uncomment this line
    not exists
        (select 1
         from table t2
         where t2.status = 1 and
               t2.user_two = t1.user_one and
               t2.user_one = t1.user_two)
```

Comment: @ParthapratimNeog Glad I could help! Please note that I have updated my answer with a `not exists` example because I have found it to [perform better than `count(*)`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3271455/2191572)

Comment: Totally makes sense. Will try it out with `not exists` and see.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` for this:

```sql
SELECT USER_ONE, USER_TWO, STATUS 
FROM mytable AS t1
WHERE USER_TWO = 'A' AND STATUS = 1 AND 
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM mytable AS t2 
                  WHERE t2.USER_TWO = t1.USER_TWO AND
                        USER_ONE = 'A' AND STATUS = 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, for some reason I got an empty response. I must have messed up the column names, I will revert back.