# Optimizing SELECT COUNT to EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query to find certain customers from a table.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM CUSTOMER
 WHERE amount <> 0
   AND customerid = 22
```

There is an index on customerid, so the DB scans all rows with customerid = 22.

Since the result is processed by checking whether the count returns zero or more than zero, how can I optimize the query? I.e. such that at the first customer row with amount <> 0 the query returns 0 else if all rows are = 0, then return 1.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759756/is-it-possible-to-select-exists-directly-as-a-bit

Comment: First customer row based on what - date?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
select case
         when exists (select *
                      from   customer
                      where  amount <> 0
                             and customerid = 22) then 1
         else 0
       end  as non_zero_exists
```

Comment: Would it be more efficient to replace 'select *' with 'select customerid' or maybe 'select 1' ?

Comment: @CarloV.Dango from memory SQL Server 2005 and up has added optimizations that makes exists and count checks like above the same speed.

Comment: @BertusKruger That only applies if the `COUNT` test against `0` is in the query, which it is not in the original question. I wonder if `TOP 1` would optimize it.

Answer (score 8):

First index on customerid and amount

```
CREATE INDEX customer_idx ON customer(customerid, amount);
```

then rewrite your query as

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT customerid
    FROM customer
    WHERE amount > 0 -- I am assuming here that amount cannot be a negative number.
    AND customerid = 22)
   SELECT 1
ELSE
   SELECT 0
```

This should result in an index seek on customer_idx.  Otherwise you'll need to scan all rows for that customer (which your question seems to imply could be a lot).

Comment: +1 the solution to *every* SQL performance question is first and foremost to create an appropriate index.

Comment: @Chris this produces `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'exists although the index bit is nice

Comment: Sorry, was coding in the SO window, always a bad decision.  Updated to use something more like your query.  +1 to your answer.

Comment: Yes, but so can long running, blocking queries that are not operating on properly indexed data.

Comment: And for what it's worth, they don't cause deadlocks.  They may exacerbate deadlocks caused by insert-heavy workloads, however.

Answer (score 4):

Seems straight forward enough

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT customerid
            FROM   customer
            WHERE  amount <> 0
                  and customerid = 22))
   SELECT 1
ELSE
   SELECT 0
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to EXISTS

```
select ISNULL((select TOP 1 1
               from customer
               where amount <> 0
                 and customerid = 22),0)
```

I already assumed that you will have an index on (customerid) or better (customerid,amount).