# Convert Bool to Bit in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqldatatypes

I need to write result of **EXISTS** function to a variable. I read that SQL Server has no 'bool' variables, so I want to store the result in a **bit** variable. And vice versa convert from 'bit' to 'bool'. How can I achieve it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [is it possible to select EXISTS directly as a bit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759756/is-it-possible-to-select-exists-directly-as-a-bit)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
DECLARE @bool BIT;

SELECT @bool = CASE WHEN EXISTS (some subquery) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

I don't know what vice versa means. SQL Server doesn't have a boolean data type, so I don't know what you want to convert a BIT to... maybe:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @bool = 1 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END;
```

If you're trying to do this in an `IF` statement:

```
IF @bool = 1
BEGIN
  PRINT 'True';
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  PRINT 'False';
END
```

If you're looking for shorthand, where you can say `IF (@bool)` instead of `IF (@bool) = 1`, sorry, but you're out of luck. If this is where you are trying to "optimize" your code and you don't have more pressing problems, go home for the day and have a beer, you've earned it. Saving two characters has already cost you more time than it will ever gain you.