# SQL query returns same record multiple times

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I'm working on the automatic register for my university project. I use RFID scanner to scan student's tagID, and use it to query my database and display results in DataGridView.

The runtime process is:

- User scans the tag (RFID_DataReceived handler fires to read the tag and executes `TagExistsQuery()` to check if the tag exists in the `Student` table of the DB)
- IF the tag DOES exist in database THEN execute `AttendanceQuery()` to match the tag with particular lecture and display the result in DGV
- IF the tag DOES NOT exist in DB THEN display error message

My problem is that the `AttendanceQuery()` produce the same record multiple times (16 to be exact) where it should be only one. This been driving me nuts for days now. Hope you will be able to help.

My code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace AutoReg
{
    public partial class RoomActiveSession : Form
    {
        // Create the serial port with basic settings
        public SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

        public int tagNo;


        public RoomActiveSession()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //Attach a method to be called when there is data waiting in the port's buffer
            port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(RFID_DataReceived);

            //Begin communications
            port.Open();
        }


        public void RFID_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            while (port.ReadChar() != 2) ;

            int v = 0;
            port.ReadChar(); // drop 1st 2 bytes - we actually only read the lower 32-bits of the code
            port.ReadChar();

            for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                int c = port.ReadChar(); // a ascii hex char
                int part = c - '0';

                // test if 'Alpha'

                if (part > 9) part -= 7;     // Quick & dirty !


                v |= part << (i * 4);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                port.ReadChar();
            }

            tagNo = v;


            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
            {

                TagExistsQuery();
            }

            ));

        }

        //SQL query that checks if the scanned tag already exists in the "Student" table
        public void TagExistsQuery()
        {
            DataTable queryResult = new DataTable();
            string ConnStr = "Data Source=DUZY;Initial Catalog=AutoRegSQL;Integrated Security=True";

            SqlConnection MyConn = new SqlConnection(ConnStr);
            MyConn.Open();

            string query = @"SELECT TagID" +
               " FROM Student " +
               " WHERE TagID = @tagNo ";

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, MyConn);

            command.Parameters.Add("tagNo", SqlDbType.Int).Value = tagNo;


            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

            adapter.Fill(queryResult);

            if (queryResult.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to match scanned tag with the Student database. Please contact help desk for assistance");
                MyConn.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                MyConn.Close();
                AttendanceQuery();

            }

        }

        //SQL query that finds the current sessionID for the given tagID by comparing curent date/time with date/time saved in DB and display result in DGV
        public void AttendanceQuery()
        {
            DataTable queryResult = new DataTable();

            string ConnStr = "Data Source=DUZY;Initial Catalog=AutoRegSQL;Integrated Security=True";

            DateTime TimePlus = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30);
            string Plus30Min = TimePlus.ToString("hh:mm tt");

            SqlConnection MyConn = new SqlConnection(ConnStr);
            MyConn.Open();


            string query = @"SELECT s.TagID, se.SessionID, '" +
               DateTime.Now +
               "' AS ScanningTime " +
               " FROM (((Student s " +
               " LEFT JOIN [CourseID-ModuleID] cm ON s.CourseID = cm.CourseID) " +
               " LEFT JOIN [ModuleID-SessionID] ms ON ms.ModuleID = cm.ModuleID) " +
               " LEFT JOIN [Session] se ON ms.SessionID = se.SessionID) " +
               " WHERE s.TagID = @tagNo " +
               " AND se.SessionDate = cast(getdate() as date) " +
               " AND se.SessionTimeStart <= @Plus30Min " +
               " AND se.SessionTimeEnd >= @Plus30Min ";

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, MyConn);

            command.Parameters.Add("tagNo", SqlDbType.Int).Value = tagNo;
            command.Parameters.Add("Plus30Min", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Plus30Min;

            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

                adapter.Fill(queryResult);

                if (queryResult.Rows.Count == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Unable to register student " + tagNo);
                    MyConn.Close();
                }
                else
                {

                    SetDataSouce(queryResult);
                    MyConn.Close();
                }
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }


        public void SetDataSouce(object source)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
        }


     }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks for your contribution so far guys:

With your massive help (thanks @user123 and others) I have managed to confirm that the following code also produce 16 records on SSMS:

```
DECLARE @Plus30Min TIME, @tagNo INT
SET @Plus30Min = DATEADD(MINUTE,30,GETDATE())
SET @tagNo = 4820427

SELECT s.TagID, se.SessionID
FROM (((Student s
LEFT JOIN [CourseID-ModuleID] cm ON s.CourseID = cm.CourseID)
LEFT JOIN [ModuleID-SessionID] ms ON ms.ModuleID = cm.ModuleID)
LEFT JOIN [Session] se ON ms.SessionID = se.SessionID)
WHERE s.TagID = @tagNo
AND se.SessionDate = cast(getdate() as date)
AND se.SessionTimeStart <= @Plus30Min
AND se.SessionTimeEnd >= @Plus30Min
```

Using INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN still produce 16 instead of 1

**EDIT CD:**

Problem solved. Noticed multiple records in one of the tables. I want to thank you everybody for your help, pointers and time spend. Beginners like me are lucky to have SO and users like yourself who are willing to help. Thank you again!

**EDIT CD2:**

It turns out that deleting multiple records from `CourseID-ModuleID` table, only limited the records produced from 16 to 4 so there is progress, but not perfection. I have tried using INNER instead of LEFT JOIN but the results remain the same.

**EDIT CD3:**
Again checked the tables, and some dummy entries where left there. You R still great, an I'm still bad in programing :)

Comment: What is the datatype for SessionTimeStart and SessionTimeEnd? You are confronting these field against a string. What do you expect to be the result of that comparison?

Comment: do you mean that the `Fill` command comes back with 16 records instead of 1 ? in that case, there is probably something amiss in your TSQL (most likely, a missing join condition). Have you tried debugging the TSQL in SQL Server Management Studio ? Also - avoid concatenating `DateTime.Now` into the TSQL - either parameterize it, or use `GETDATE()` / `GETUTCDATE()` as a TSQL operation

Comment: Just double checked it in SSMS - for both is time(7)

Comment: Not an answer bu I have a strong feeling that a compare between a string and a time will not yield a correct result

Comment: yep, Fill command comes back with 16 records

Comment: The LEFT JOIN is most probably the culprit in returning multiple records because it is returning records from Student even if there are no matches in your joined tables. It would be far easier to diagnose this by running your query in SSMS by itself and build it up piece by piece.

Comment: Why don't you try with INNER JOIN?

Comment: Produce the same result

Comment: IF INNER JOIN also return same numbers then use GROUP BY s.TagID, se.SessionID

Comment: Please dump your input values `Plus30Min` and `tagNo`, and one row out of duplicate 16 rows data. It would help if you could provide sample mini table, but that's **not really** required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this query (replacing the YOURVALUEs) ...

```
DECLARE @Plus30Min DATETIME, @tagNo INT
SET @Plus30Min = DATEADD(MINUTE,30,GETDATE())
SET @tagNo = YOURVALUE

SELECT s.TagID, se.SessionID,
FROM (((Student s
LEFT JOIN [CourseID-ModuleID] cm ON s.CourseID = cm.CourseID)
LEFT JOIN [ModuleID-SessionID] ms ON ms.ModuleID = cm.ModuleID)
LEFT JOIN [Session] se ON ms.SessionID = se.SessionID)
WHERE s.TagID = @tagNo
AND se.SessionDate = cast(getdate() as date)
AND se.SessionTimeStart <= @Plus30Min
AND se.SessionTimeEnd >= @Plus30Min
```

... in your SQL Server and see if multiple records come back when it should be one (more than likely it is); if it's a database issue (and not a `C#` issue), 99% of the time, it's a `JOIN` that's the cause.  Here are some ways I troubleshoot multiple records on `JOIN` queries that have always worked to catch the error:

1. Check each table individually used in the `JOIN` or `SELECT` query to see if you can find multiple records in each table when there should be only one (often the problem - one duplicate can create a huge mess).
2. Sometimes when people code `LEFT JOIN`, they really need an `INNER JOIN` (or vice versa).  `JOIN` mix-ups can also be a huge problem when getting duplicates.
3. Double check the `WHERE` clause or the `JOIN` conditions.  Sometimes a filter is missing on a clause that would eliminate some records.
4. When you get a database query that produces no duplicates, use that ***IF*** the above query on the database end results is the 16 records.

**UPDATE:**

Excellent!  Now, change your joins to INNER, and see if you get multiple records.  If so, check each table (Student, CourseID, ModuleID, Session) to ensure there are no duplicates (or multiple records) when there should be only one using the same parameters you see in your query (on the `JOIN` or `WHERE` conditions).  If you should have multiple records for a condition, you'll want to specify in your `JOIN` condition (or the `WHERE` clause) to a point where you get only one record.

Comment: Im totally new to SQL Server. It will take me a while to adjust the syntax (throws a lot of errors)

Comment: @jaspernorth I updated the code to reflect what I think you're trying to query on SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks for that. I would like to SET @Plus30Min to be the current time +30 min. How do I do that?

Comment: @jaspernorth Use: DATEADD(MINUTE,30,GETDATE())

Comment: following your troubleshoot guide solved my problem. I have noticed multiple records in [CourseID-ModuleID] table. Each module was listed 4 times for some reason,  4x4=16 :) Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @jaspernorth You're welcome; glad you identified it.  Hopefully, this helps you in the future if you have a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you get 16 rows instead of 1 because you can have several courses per student, several modules per course, several sessions per module. If you make your joins the other way around you should get 1 row (Student LEFT JOIN Session LEFT JOIN Module LEFT JOIN Course, assuming a course as several modules and not the opposite.).
But you will then get a row for a student who for example has no session.

I guess what you really wanted to use is INNER JOIN.

Also instead of selecting then counting if there are more than zero rows, you could use SQL 'EXISTS'.

Comment: In the DB i only have 1 student on 1 course which contains of several modules, several sessions per module

Comment: So you with your initial query (LEFT JOIN + that order) you get 1 student x 1 cours x [number of course] x [number of sessions] rows, filtered by the WHERE clause keeping only the lines satisfying the session conditions.

Comment: correct, but still returns 16 instead of 1 (there could be only one session occurring in that time for the student - student can only be on one lecture at the time)

Comment: using INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN produce same results

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how could I modify my query to use EXIST? It seems to be much more siuted for the task...

Comment: I lack of time right now to illustrate everything, but here you'll find an example of query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759756/is-it-possible-to-select-exists-directly-as-a-bit

Comment: Then when you check the results, the first cell of the first row should be 1 or 0 (true or false). It should also be possible to get only the scalar value 1 or 0 or use an output parameter instead of getting a datatable.

Answer (score 0):

1. Confirm tagid is unique in user table.
2. Add `se.SessionTimeStart` and `se.SessionTimeEnd` to the query results.  I suspect some never-ending sessions started in the past.
3. make sure this is a 24 hour clock, not a 12 hour clock:

   string Plus30Min = TimePlus.ToString("hh:mm tt");